# Not able to conver json to dataset, datatable

Tags: json, csv

I am writing a small tool to convert json to csv. First I try to convert json to Dataset or Datatable but failing.

The Json string is:

```
{
  "id1": {
    "id": "id11",
    "cards": {
      "1": {
        "id": "test11",
        "fingerprint": "test11",
        "last4": "test11",
        "exp_month": 7,
        "exp_year": 2019,
        "brand": "test11"
      },
      "0": {
        "id": "test12",
        "fingerprint": "test12",
        "last4": "test12",
        "exp_month": 7,
        "exp_year": 2020,
        "brand": "Visa"
      },
      "2": {
        "id": "test13",
        "fingerprint": "test13",
        "last4": "test13",
        "exp_month": 8,
        "exp_year": 2020,
        "brand": "Visa"
      }
    }
  },
  "id2": {
    "id": "id21",
    "cards": {
      "1": {
        "id": "test21",
        "fingerprint": "test21",
        "last4": "test21",
        "exp_month": 7,
        "exp_year": 2019,
        "brand": "MC"
      },
      "0": {
        "id": "test22",
        "fingerprint": "test22",
        "last4": "test5",
        "exp_month": 2,
        "exp_year": 2020,
        "brand": "Visa"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried

```
DataSet ds = JObject.Parse(jsonContent)["root"].ToObject<DataSet>();

DataTable dt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(jsonContent);
```

But it does not work. Gives this error with first one:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in JsonToCsv.exe
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

This error with second one:

> An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
>
> Additional information: Unexpected JSON token when reading DataTable. Expected StartArray, got StartObject. Path '', line 1, position 1.

Any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: I'd expect that serialising to a DataTable would expect an array - and each item in the array would become a row in the table. However, your JSON is an object, not an array. That's what it means when it says _"expected startArray, got startObject"_. It won't automatically know to look at the properties and realise they are meant to be the rows. You'll have to either supply the JSON in a better format or, if that's not possible, deserialise the data to a different structure, and then if necessary write some code to transform it into your desired format.

Comment: And I'm fairly sure your first error is because your json doesn't have any property called "root" (but I'm not 100% sure about that). Even then, serialising it to a DataSet would still not work - there's nothing recognisably a list of lists (i.e. a list of tables), in your JSON.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but unfortunately i don't have option to change the file format.

Comment: In that case you have to choose a different structure in c# to deserialise it too. A Dictionary would be a possibility I think. Or you could cheat a bit and use dynamic

Comment: Also it might help to show us the intended structure of the final CSV... after all CSV is a flat structure, where your JSON is a nested structure, so it's not immediately obvious exactly what the final output should look like

Comment: I am able to iterate through the elements and read the data into structure and it is working,

Comment: ok, great, if you fixed it you have the option to write it as the answer below (you can answer your own question, and also accept your own answer, and others can then vote on it :-))

Comment: the csv will have all those nodes as columns, like this
ActId,CustId,Id,Fingerprint,Last4,Exp_month,Exp_year,Brand

Comment: Thanks but without your answer below I wouldn't have know which exact data fields (or keys) you were planning to use for ActId or CustId, would I? There's nothing with those names in the JSON. Don't forget I have no contextual information about your data, I can only see what's written in front of me. That's what I meant...you have to specify it with an exact mapping (e.g. this input field -> that output field) if you want someone else to help you. We can't guess. Anyway that's just a note for the future if you have to write requirements for others to follow. I've upvoted your answer.

Comment: I required data in linear format and that's why i put all column in one class, but that was secondary, the primary attempt was to get this json parsed into any structure. I wanted to deserialize it using statement as in question, but that could not work,

Comment: ok but that has very little to do with anything I've just said. And the original point, if you remember, was that in order to deserialise into something else useful we needed to know what you intended to do with the data afterwards :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to parse json into a list and then converted list to csv. the code to parse json to list is as follows:

```
public class Card
{
    public string ActId { get; set; }
    public string CustId { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Fingerprint { get; set; }
    public string Last4 { get; set; }
    public int Exp_month { get; set; }

    public int Exp_year { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
}


public static List<Card> JsonToCSV(string JsonContent)
{
    var ds = JObject.Parse(JsonContent);

    var cards = new List<Card>();

    foreach (var item in ds)
    {

        var crds= JObject.Parse(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(item.Value["cards"].ToString()).ToString());

        foreach (var crd  in crds)
        {
            var card =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Card>(crd.Value.ToString());
            card.ActId= item.Key;
            card.CustId= item.Value["id"].ToString();
            cards.Add(card);        
        }
    }
    return cards;
}
```